# Почему не меняется цвет в ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-material, android-style

```
    <style name="ActionBarWhite" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarWhite.Color</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarWhite.Color" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#3333ff</item>
</style>
```

Почему не меняется ActionBar? раньше работало с Holo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За цвет `ActionBar`-a теперь отвечает атрибут `colorPrimary`, т.е. надо в тему добавить строку (при использовании support либы префикс `android:` перед названием атрибута не нужен):

```
<item name="colorPrimary">#3333ff</item>
```

Вот немного доков по теме: [тык](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/material/theme.html)